Improving OCR accuracy with pytesseract for processing manga images
def get_string(img_path):
    img = cv2.imread(img_path)
    img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=2, fy=2, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_processed = cv2.threshold(cv2.GaussianBlur(gray_img, (5, 5), 0), 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    result = pytesseract.image_to_string(img_processed, lang="eng")
    return result

I'm using pytesseract and OpenCV to extract text from manga images, but the extracted text has missing words and misspellings. I'm looking for advice on how to improve the accuracy of my OCR process.

Can you share some example images and the output that you have?
